# Error: syntax error, unexpected "Identifier", expecting "end of file"

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

This is a sample program I am doing for my COBOL class and I had a few questions about an error code I am getting when I tried to compile through the command line. Please see below. Below the COBOL will be my terminal code. How can I fix the "unexpected indentifier?"

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.      SAMPLE135.
   AUTHOR.          ME.

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.


   DATA DIVISION.
   77 FIELD-A PIC 9(2).
   77 FIELD-B PIC 9(2).
   77 FIELD-C PIC 9(3) VALUE ZERO.
   77 FIELD-D PIC 9(3) VALUE ZERO.

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   FIRST-PARAGRAPH.
       MOVE ZEROS TO FIELD-A FIELD-B.
       PERFORM SECOND-PARAGRAPH.
       PERFORM THIRD-PARAGRAPH.
       PERFORM SECOND-PARAGRAPH.
       PERFORM WRITE-DATA.
       STOP RUN.      

   SECOND-PARAGRAPH.
       ADD 10 TO FIELD-A.
       ADD 20 TO FIELD-B.

   THIRD-PARAGRAPH.
       MULTIPLY FIELD-A BY FIELD-B GIVING FIELD-C.
       DIVIDE FIELD-A INTO FIELD-B GIVING FIELD-D.

   WRITE-DATA.
       DISPLAY FIELD-A.
       DISPLAY FIELD-B.
       DISPLAY FIELD-C.
       DISPLAY FIELD-D.

   END PROGRAM.



Sample2.cbl:9: Error: syntax error, unexpected "Identifier", expecting "end of file"
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the '77' data items in the wrong place,also indent. Also make sure that the Field names start in **area B** (unless using free format). try

```
DATA DIVISION.

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   77  FIELD-A          PIC 9(2).
   77  FIELD-B          PIC 9(2).
   77  FIELD-C          PIC 9(3) VALUE ZERO.
   77  FIELD-D          PIC 9(3) VALUE ZERO.
```

---

In Cobol code it is generally considered better to only use '.' when they are absolutely needed (before procedures) i.e

```
SECOND-PARAGRAPH.
    ADD 10              TO FIELD-A
    ADD 20              TO FIELD-B

    .
THIRD-PARAGRAPH.
```

---

Finally it is also standard practice indent **TO** and **PIC** statements
as I have

Answer (score 1):

The WORKING-STORAGE SECTION header must come before the 77-level definitions.

```
       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       77 FIELD-A PIC 9(2).
       77 FIELD-B PIC 9(2).
       77 FIELD-C PIC 9(3) VALUE ZERO.
       77 FIELD-D PIC 9(3) VALUE ZERO.
```

You're also missing the program name in the end marker.

```
       END PROGRAM SAMPLE135.
```

Comment: Either that or `END PROGRAM.` is superfluous, depending on whether being taught the verbiage to support the idea of verbose :-)